# raspberrypi2 - How to install GUI for windows 10 IoT

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I have installed Linux on the pi before. I now need to install windows 10 for IoT. Whats the best way for me to do it?
I know that I can connect using powershell. Is there a GUI for controlling it?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install IoT core easily on a Pi there is a tool from Microsoft called the

> [IoT Core Dashboard.](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Downloads.htm)

This tool is an easy to use setup wizard that will format and install the Win10 IoT image.

Once the installation is finished you can access the dashboard of your pi through the browser from this tool or by typing in the local IP address.

There is an easy to use guide for installation found here: [Getting Started](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/GetStarted/SetUpYourDevice.htm)

You may also connect using powershell after your initial setup: [Connect with PowerShell](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm)